# Passing arguments to another C++ source file

Tags: c++, class, argument-passing

I have been trying to implement a class function for about a week now to no avail.  Normally, I would be satisfied to put the logic in the header file, however, the ACML library conflicts with my use of the "complex" include.  Long story short, I need to make all calls to the C ACML library from a separate cpp file.  Below is my code and I have been unable to get it working.  I am using Visual Studio 2013 preview and I am getting the following compilation error:

> ```
> acml_lapack.h(8): error C3861: 'dgetrf_c': identifier not found
> ```

How do I call and pass arguments to a function physically located in another *.cpp file?  I have found other posts on the subject but I must be missing something as my code will not work.

Header File:

```
// acml_lapack.h
#ifndef __ACML_LAPACK
#define __ACML_LAPACK

void dgetrf(int m, int n, double *a, int *ipiv, int &info)
{
     if (m && n)
    dgetrf_c(&m, &n, a, &m, ipiv, &info);
}
#endif
```

Additional *.cpp file:

```
// acml_lapack.cpp
#include <acml.h>
#include "acml_lapack.h"

void dgetrf_c(int *m, int *n, double *a, int *lda, int *ipiv, int *info)
extern "C" {
     void dgetrf_(int *m, int *n, double *a, int *lda, int *ipiv, int *info);  //call C AMD Core Math Library lapack
}
```

Main source file:

```
// source.cpp
#include <acml_lapack.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
// **** Start test acml ****
double A[2][2];
A[0][0] = 1;
A[0][1] = 2;
A[1][0] = 3;
A[1][1] = 4;

cout << "before: " << endl;
cout << A[0][0] << A[0][1] << endl;
cout << A[1][0] << A[1][1] << endl;

int LDA = 2;
int * output;

//call external function from another cpp file
dgetrf(2, 2, *A, &LDA, *output); 

cout << "after: " << endl;
cout << A[0][0] << A[0][1] << endl;
cout << A[1][0] << A[1][1] << endl;

// **** END TEST ****
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the additional .cpp file to

```
// acml_lapack.cpp
#include <acml.h>
#include "acml_lapack.h"

extern "C" {
     void dgetrf_(int *m, int *n, double *a, int *lda, int *ipiv, int *info);  //call C AMD
}

void dgetrf_c(int *m, int *n, double *a, int *lda, int *ipiv, int *info)
{
     dgetrf_(m, n, a, lda, ipiv, info);  //call C AMD Core Math Library lapack
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the function declaration in your header:

```
void dgetrf_c(int *m, int *n, double *a, int *lda, int *ipiv, int *info);
```

right before `dgetrf` definition.  Note that it's generally a bad idea to put a function *definition* (ie. function body) in a header like you do for `dgetrf`.  The reason is that you will end up with several definitions of the same function scattered all over your code: one definition for each inclusion of the header containing the definition in other files (most probably cpp files), and the compiler will not know which one to choose as the legitimate one. The cure for that problem is to put the `dgetrf` code in a cpp file, and only provide the function *declaration* in the header file.

Comment: like this?    void dgetrf(int m, int n, double *a, int *ipiv, int &info)
 {
  void dgetrf_c(int *m, int *n, double *a, int *lda, int *ipiv, int *info);
  if (m && n)
   dgetrf_c(&m, &n, a, &m, ipiv, &info);
 }

I am still getting this error: 

1>Source.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl dgetrf(int,int,double *,int *,int &)" already defined in acml_lapack.obj
1>acml_lapack.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dgetrf_ referenced in function "void __cdecl dgetrf_c(int *,int *,double *,int *,int *,int *)" 1>C:\...\x64\Debug\Cardinal.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: Indeed, if I add the declaration to my header it refuses to compile stating that it is defined in multiple places (e.g. both cpp files).  Is it even possible to pass arguments from one source file to another and back without writing an interface?

Comment: What do you mean? Arguments are syntactic elements of functions, source files don't have arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The function declaration is not visible in your header file. If you need the declaration to be visible, then you must include other header files within your own. In general however, you do not want the function *definition* to exist in a header file as you are doing. The reason is that if your dependencies are shaped the right way, you'll cause a function to be defined multiple times within one compiler unit, which will fail to build.

In addition, your main source file has `#include <acml_lapack.h>` rather than `#include "acml_lapack.h"`, which is a problem.

Comment: Fixed the #include, although I still don't see how to pass an argument back and forth between source files without double declaring the function.  I am beginning to think this is not possible without writing an interface between executables.